# how to find latitude and longitude of a user while GPS is on

Tags: android, gps

I have developed an android application in which gps of the is turn on any time. Now how i can find the latitude and longitude of the user. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

To access current location information through location providers, we need to set permissions with android manifest file.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is used when we use network location provider for our Android app. But, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is providing permission for both providers. INTERNET permission is must for the use of network provider.

Create LocationManager instance as reference to the location service

For any background Android Service, we need to get reference for using it. Similarly, location service reference will be created using getSystemService() method. This reference will be added with the newly created LocationManager instance as follows.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Request current location from LocationManager

After creating the location service reference, location updates are requested using requestLocationUpdates() method of LocationManager. For this function, we need to send the type of location provider, number of seconds, distance and the LocationListener object over which the location to be updated.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Receive location update from LocationListener on change of location

LocationListener will be notified based on the distance interval specified or the number seconds.

This example provides current location update using GPS provider. Entire Android app code is as follows,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
}
```

XML files for layout and android manifest are as shown below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```